# React - Giving a function to my Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance

I'm struggling to update the state of my Parent component from the Child. To do that, I want to pass as argument to my child a function that update the parent's state:

```
export class Login extends Component {
      updateTurn() {
        console.log("UPDATE")
        this.setState(
            prevState => {
                UPDATING
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
          ROUTING MANAGEMENT
          <Route path="/play/pledge">
                <Pledge data={this.state.data} updateTurn={this.updateTurn}/>
          </Route>
          ROUTING MANAGEMENT
    }  
}
export class Game extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.data = this.props.data;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={"game"}>
                    { this.props.children }
                </div>
                <div className={"next"}>
                    <Link to={Launcher.getRandomGame()}>
                        <button className={"button"} onClick={this.props.updateTurn}>Next</button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happened,  even to the `console.log()`

Comment: I think youre calling the Pledge instead of Game component.

Comment: What is `<Pledge>`? Is this a custom component? If so, please include its code.

Comment: What's the `Pledge` component that accepts your `incrementByOne`? Where is `Game` used? We can't even tell which component here is the child of which, `Game` and `Login` seem unrelated.

Comment: `this.data = this.props.data;` is an anti pattern. Since the value of `this.props` changes each time React calls `render()`, you should access it directly rather than saving it to a class variable.

Comment: `ROUTING MANAGEMENT` is invalid JavaScript. Either make this a legitimate comment or, better yet, just remove it.

Comment: Why is `updateTurn()` in the `Login` component? What does turns have to do with logging in?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Pledge data={this.state.data} updateTurn={this.updateTurn}/>
```

The problem is that you are passing the function to some component named `Pledge`, but you should use `Game` instead:

```
<Game data={this.state.data} updateTurn={this.updateTurn}/>
```